# Is there a reader for iPhone or iPad that supports many formats?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm looking for a reader application that can open many ebook formats, specifically I am looking for pdf, djvu, epub, fb2 and txt.

Answer (score 1):

[Book Reader Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/book-reader-pro/id555994170?mt=8) is what you are looking for. The ebook file format support is outstanding. The supported file formats are  PDF/EPUB/CHM/DJVU/FB2/CBZ and XPS.

[Stanza](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/stanza/id284956128?l=en&mt=8) would be another good choice but I'm not sure about it file format support.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please add some details about why you are recommending this apps and which of the formats asked for they support. The idea is for the answer to stand alone.